# UISlider not ticking smoothly every milliseconds

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3, uislider

I'm making a videoplayer app, where I have a `uislider` to show the progress of the video. 
The `UISlider` updates his value every millisecond.

```
   func setCurrentValue(value: Double) {
        self.slider.setValue(Float(value), animated: false)
        log.debug("SLIDER VALUE = \(self.slider.value)")
    }
```

When i look at the log I see that the slider has value that I would expect, but when I run it looks like its ticking every second and not smoothly like I would expect.

Any help?

Comment: How are you updating the slider? What is calling this function?

Comment: how you calling updateslider ?

Comment: We are using Redux for calling update slider. But basicly this is the inteval:         let interval = CMTime(seconds:1/60, preferredTimescale: CMTimeScale(NSEC_PER_SEC))

Comment: only call the function again like recursion after delay some time interval, i think you can use perform selector method with delay and you have to set the value Slider.value

Answer (score 1):

Use the following snippet

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(WHATEVER TIME LIMIT YOU WANT, animations: {
  self.slider.setValue(Float(value), animated:true)
})
```